# Ocultar o Mostrar campos de formulario en Yii2

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii2

Buenas soy nuevo en yii2 y quería saber si hay una forma de ocultar ciertas opciones de algún formulario generado con el crud de gii.
Básicamente quiero que en la opción de crear algún registro ,la opción de estatus (Que es un radioList para mostrar el estado activo o inactivo) no se muestre a la hora de crear un registro y por defecto sea 1. Y cuando quiera actualizar algún registro pueda modificar el estatus y la opción me aparezca.
Quisiera saber si hay una opción de hacerlo desde el controlador o desde el model.

Este es mi form.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este mi model.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es parte de mi controlador.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Luis, es muy complicado comprender el planteamiento mientras falten datos. Completa la pregunta colocando el código fuente involucrado. Te invito a [realizar un recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que obtengas tu primera medalla. También puedes consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En controller asignar el estado por defecto después de instanciar el modelo:

```
public function actionCreate() {
  $model=new Clientes();
  $model->estatus=1;
}
```

En vista solo pintar campo si registro no es nuevo:

```
<?php if (!$model->isNewRecord): ?>
  <?= $form->field($model, 'estatus')->... ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```